# import dependences with ant ivy

Tags: ant, liferay, jira, ivy

I'm trying to build a Liferay portlet (jira-metrics-portlet) with ant ivy.

But I get the error:

```
[javac] The import com.atlassian cannot be resolved
```

How can I import this package with ivy? I only found solutions for mavens.

Answer (score 0):

Try following,

In your SDK, open **ivy.xml** file.

add dependency like following

```
 <dependencies defaultconf="default">
        <dependency name="atlassian" org="com.atlassian" rev="1.1" />
...
```

in **ivy-setting.xml**, add your repo links, if you have any.

```
<resolvers>
        <ibiblio m2compatible="true" name="asu-gibson" root="https://gibson.asu.edu/maven" />
```

You can directly put the *.jar files in to portlet/WEB-INF/lib folder, also.

Comment: the dependency is now in my lib folder, but i will get the same error. 
Do I have to link my portlet to my lib-folder? 
If yes how can I do this?